# ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 16 layers into a model with 0 layers

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I came across some answers that said that the pretrained model weight files get automatically downloaded when we declare it in the **.keras/models/** directory. `vgg=VGG16(weights='imagenet')` I managed to locate the file from the directory and copied it to my working directory. When i try to load the model, the script returns with the error

```
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 16 layers into 
a model with 0 layers.
```

What should I do?

My source code is as follows

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Concatenate([image_model, language_model]))
model.add(LSTM(1000, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.load_weights('./models/vgg16_weights.h5')
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Nadam(), 
metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit([images, captions], next_words, batch_size=512, epochs=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the newer versions of Keras you don't need to define model architecture and load weights instead you can directly load VGG16 model from Keras like this

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
```

[Here](https://keras.io/applications/) is the link to other models

Comment: After trying what you suggested the error still persisted. I commented out the line where I defined the vgg model. After commenting out the .load_weights line, a new ValueError arose which stated that no model has been created which is very odd as I have added layers after model=Sequential() and before model.compile.

Comment: The code is pretty much the same. I tried changing Concatenate to concatenate but it returned an error that stated the concatenate layer was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor.

Comment: The only change has been `model.load_weights('./models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5', by_name=True)`

Comment: Why are you trying to load weights because I don't think you need to load weights explicitly.

Comment: Tried doing that too, comes up with the error **This model has never been called, thus its weights have not yet been created, so no summary can be displayed. Build the model first (e.g. by calling it on some test data)**